# Laravel Request doesn't have parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('page/{id},{time}', 'OpController@op');
```

Now my method is simply:

```
public function op(Request $request, $id, $time)
{

        dump($request->all());
        dump($id);
}
```

If I call that with `/op/hello,123` I get this dump:

```
$request->all() -> []
$id -> "hello"
```

Is there any reasons that `$request` doesn't have the parameters?

`$request->input('id')` returns `null`

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
$request->input('param');
```

Works when url query param, example: `url?param=text` and all the params of POST.

That doesn't work with route param `'myurl/{param}'`

Answer (score 2):

Because `Request` shouldn't have URL vars in it. Request used for getting data from forms etc. You should use `$id` and `$time` variables if you want to get data from URL in this case.

You can contents of Request object by using `dd($request)`;

Comment: @giò - the verb is irrelevant, anything in either the Query String or encoded form data can be collected with a Request input.

Answer (score -1):

Just change your route with below code....

```
Route::get('page/{id}/{time}', 'OpController@op');
```

And write url like /page/hello/123

Comment: `,` is allowed and works fine in URLs, so it's not a reason why Request doesn't have those vars in it.